# How to insert package.txt into scripts object of package.json file?

Tags: go, glide-golang

My package.txt contains:-

```
 "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --fix .",
    "lint-check": "eslint .",
  }
```

I am creating a react app using `npx create-react-app <project_name> --template typescript` . Once my React app is created under the project name it will have `package.json` file. Now I have stored package.txt file inside another directory & I want to merge the scripts of package.txt with the `scripts` of  `package.json` of the project without losing project's script details. In short, it should just append in the script section of package.txt with  project's package.json .

I am using Golang & I have tried several ways :-

```
func demo() {
    projDir := filepath.Join(react.ProjectName, "package.json")
    f, err := os.OpenFile(projDir, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()
    if _, err := f.WriteString(packageJSON); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    
}
```

It gets append at last of project's package.json but it doesn't get append with script part of package.json. Please help me

Comment: I replaced & I am getting this error ```cannot use packageJSON (variable of type string) as []byte value in argument to os.WriteFile``` @Zombo

Comment: @Zombo It replaces the entire package.json with package.txt . I want package.txt file should append in the script object of package.json . How to do that ?

Comment: glide is deprecated since several years.

Comment: @Volker What does it mean ? Can you please be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you package.txt file contains:

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --fix .",
    "lint-check": "eslint .",
}
```

And package.json file contains:

```json
{
    "some": "other fields",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js",
        "dev": "nodemon"
    },
    "another": "other fields"
}
```

If you need the job you mentioned, then do it manually.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    demo()
}

func demo() {
    // getting .txt file content
    txtByte, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./package.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    txtString := string(txtByte)

    // getting main lines to append
    txtLines := getMainLines(txtString)

    // getting .json file content
    jsonByte, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./package.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    jsonString := string(jsonByte)

    // getting index of where the main lines will be append on .json file
    indexOfAppend := getIndex(jsonString, `"scripts": {`)

    // merging
    finalString := merge(jsonString, indexOfAppend, txtLines)

    fmt.Println(finalString)
}

func getMainLines(txtString string) string {
    // eleminating `"scripts": {` part from .txt file
    txtString = strings.TrimSpace(strings.TrimPrefix(txtString, `"scripts": {`))

    // eleminating `}` part from .txt file
    txtString = strings.TrimSpace(strings.TrimSuffix(txtString, `}`))

    // finally return main lines
    return txtString
}

func getIndex(jsonString, subStr string) int {
    // identifying index of where to append
    index := strings.Index(jsonString, subStr)
    if index == -1 {
        fmt.Println("invalid sub-string")
    }

    // index is the value of first char of subStr
    // so adding the length upto `{`
    return index + 12 //  `"scripts": {` -->  have 12 chars
}

func merge(jsonString string, indexOfAppend int, txtLines string) string {
    // newStr is consist of 3 part
    // first: content of .json file upto `"scripts": {`
    // second: content of main lines
    // thirs: last content of .json file
    newStr := jsonString[:indexOfAppend] + txtLines + jsonString[indexOfAppend:]

    return newStr
}
```

Take care of space, tabs, comma and other stuffs accordingly.

And finally write the final result/string to your existing package.json file:

```golang
    // now write the final result to package.json file
    err = ioutil.WriteFile("./package.json", []byte(finalString), 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("successfully merged")
```